# сумма трёх переменных в одной строке

Tags: python

как сделать так чтобы получилась сумма трёх ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ? Есть у нас a, b, c, ну тип через сплит:

```
a,b,c=map(int, input().split()) 
print(sum(a,b,c))
```

выдаёт ошибку что `sum()` работает только с двумя переменными, пж, помогите.

Comment: `a+b+c` не работает?

Comment: `sum` суммирует итератор (например, коллекцию), а не отдельные переменные, для отдельных переменных есть простой `+`

Comment: можно обойтись без промежуточных переменных `print(sum(map(int, input().split())))`

Answer (score 1):

Создай список из этих переменных:

```
print(sum([a, b, c])
```

А еще лучше - в кортеж, так как от неизменяемый и (обычно) заминает меньше памяти:

```
print(sum((a, b, c))  # здесь круглые скобки создают объект типа tuple
```

Оба приведенных выше способа нужны только в случае, когда переменных не фиксированное кол-во (например, вводятся n значений через n-1 пробелов). Иначе, не стоит лишний раз создавать стековый кадр. Тем более, скорее всего, интерпретатор оптимизирует выражение в обычную сумму вместо функции.

Как правильно заметил MBo, вывод лучше сделать сразу в коллекцию.

Comment: Тогда уже можно довести до универсальности, делая из инпута список или кортеж